# jQuery window resize error

Tags: jquery, console.log, window-resize, jquery-events

I'm getting an error in the console when i'm using $(window).resize()

I've created a pen to illustrate what is happening: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LRYGxK?editors=1111

```
var bg = $('.inner');
$(window).resize('resizeBackground');

function resizeBackground() {
    bg.height($(window).height() + 60);
    console.log(bg.height());
}
resizeBackground();
```

The error I get in the console is:

Uncaught TypeError: ((n.event.special[g.origType] || (intermediate value)).handle || g.handler).apply is not a function

Not sure where i'm going wrong to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

you can call your `resizeBackground` function like given below on resize window.

```
$(window).resize(function resizeBackground() {
    bg.height($(window).height() + 60);
    console.log(bg.height()); 
 });
```

**working demo** : [link](https://jsfiddle.net/yashsoni789/jntmydw6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is as simple as this

```
('resizeBackground')
```

is passing a string -

Just pass the function

```
(resizeBackground)
```

See here: http://codepen.io/alexjamesbrown/pen/yaLZzj

Full example

```
var bg = $('.inner');
$(window).resize(resizeBackground);

function resizeBackground() {
    bg.height($(window).height() + 60);
    console.log(bg.height());
}
resizeBackground();
```

To simplify it, you could try this:

http://codepen.io/alexjamesbrown/pen/pEogAL

```
var bg = $('.inner');
$(window).resize(function(){
    bg.height($(window).height() + 60);
    console.log(bg.height());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$(window).resize() call requires a handler function - Function(Event eventObject).

Use it like that

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    resizeBackground();
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Answer (score 0):

What about to try something like the code bofore:

```js
var bg = $('.inner');

// If you want that in load (just for explanation)
$(document).ready(function() {
  resizeBackground();
});
// On window resize
$(window).resize(function() {
  resizeBackground();
});

// Generic function, called by the callbacks..
function resizeBackground() {
    bg.height($(window).height() + 60);
    console.log(bg.height());
}
```

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="inner"></div>
```

This way you are calling your created function inside then ".resize()" callback syntax.

You can get more about in the official jQuery resize documentation: https://api.jquery.com/resize/